# Russian currency name is not in style with the site

Tags: bug, salary-calculator

Russian users are currently presented with this kind of page in salary calculator[image]
"руб" part here

1. is in cyrillic, although all the site is in latin characters
2. is textual and not symbolic, thus should be after salary amount, separated by whitespace. Or simply changed with [rubles symbol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ruble_sign) ₽

Comment: Tempted to compare this to those pluralization "bugs": the meaning is perfectly clear, and making it semantically correct would eat up dev time.

Comment: @StephenLeppik Take a look at the middle value. "руб660,000" can not ever be called "perfectly" clear :)

Comment: Ah. Imgur is blocked on my host so I missed that. That makes the problem so much more clear.

Comment: Heh. Just thought to post same bug. But posted couple of others :)

Comment: I wouldn't recommend the `₽`, since it doesn't display properly at least in my browser.

Comment: Nor mine, but then, I'm not Russian nor do I regularly deal with rubles. I'd probably ensure my setup could display that symbol if I were / did. :-)

Comment: @HolyBlackCat, ₽ is an unicode symbol, what do you mean by "doesn't display properly"?

Comment: @Zhigalin They probably mean that their font stack doesn’t support it.

Comment: The proper ways to spell that in Russian is either `410 000 руб.` or `410 000 ₽`. If you output non-US currency, the number should be printed according to non-US locale.